# How we supourt IPV6 for reachability

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipv6, reachability

I am using this code for check internet connection. What change I have to made for suppourt in IPV6. Please help any help would be appreciate.

```
 public enum ReachabilityType {
        case WWAN,
        WiFi,
        NotConnected
    }
    public class Reachability: NSObject {
        class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
            var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
            zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
            zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
            let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
            }
            var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
            if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
                return false
            }
            let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
            let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
            return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_md.html, monitoring the "zero address" `0.0.0.0` monitors both IPv4 and IPv6 connection status. What issues do you have in an IPv6 network? Where does the code fail?

Comment: some one say apple reject your app. if you doing this

Comment: There are some issues *claiming* that https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift does not work with IPv6 and caused Apple rejection, for example https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/issues/119. As far as I can see, it was never confirmed that the Reachability code is the culprit. – I haven't tested it yet, so I can neither confirm nor deny it, but *"some one say apple reject your app"* without concrete information seems a bit vague to me.

Comment: As far as we can tell, there is no IPV6 issue with Reachability.swift. If there is a crash, Apple seem to be adding the "make sure you support IPV6" message on the rejection notice, irrespective of the cause.